# Scala lazy val interpretation

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I am learning Scala basics. I just came across the `lazy val` concept. I have following code snippets which work without errors/warnings

### Case 1

```
lazy val a = 10 + b
lazy val b = 5
println(a)
```

### Case 2

```
lazy val a = 10 + b
val b = 5
println(a)
```

### Case 3

```
val a = 10 + b
lazy val b = 5
println(a)
```

I understand how `case 1 & 2` work. But I don't understand how the code in `case 3` is working without error/warning. How is Scala able to evaluate the value of `a` when `b` is not yet defined?

### EDIT

I am not running this code in `Scala REPL`. I have saved the code in case 3 in file called `lazyVal.scala`. I am executing it using `scala lazyVal.scala`. I think scala interprets the code in the file.

If I change the code in `lazyVal.scala` to

```
val a = 10 + b
val b = 5
println(a)
```

And execute it using `scala lazyVal.scala` I do get warning

```
/Users/varun.risbud/scalaRepo/src/Chapter1/lazyVal.scala:1: warning: Reference to uninitialized value b
val a = 10 + b
         ^
one warning found
10
```

Also If I change the code to create object and extend App it works

```
object lazyVal extends App {
    val a = 10 + b
    lazy val b = 5
    println(a)
}
➜  Chapter1 scalac lazyVal.scala
➜  Chapter1 scala lazyVal
15
```

My `scala version` is `2.12.1` if that makes any difference.

Comment: Are you just trying out these cases in a REPL in this order? If so, the `b` in case 3 is probably just the last `b` defined from case 2. Otherwise, I am getting an `error: not found: value b`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic since the problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @Alec Please take a look it at question edit section.

Comment: @Alec actually it's even more interesting as a scripting question, since the semantics are different for each way of running the code. The script runner wraps the snippet in a main function, where you see different bugs and behaviors than running from REPL. Let alone running as App.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Statements in a constructor execute in textual order, which is why you get a warning when the initialization of `a` refers to the uninitialized `b`. It's a common error to compose a class in a way that you don't even get the warning. (There's a FAQ tutorial about that.)

The same text is forbidden in a local sequence of statements:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

locally {
val a = 10 + b
lazy val b = 5
println(a)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:13: error: forward reference extends over definition of value a
       val a = 10 + b
                    ^
```

As members of a class or object, the lazy member is evaluated "on demand", when `a` is evaluated during construction.

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object X {
val a = 10 + b
lazy val b = 5
println(a)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object X

scala> X
15
res1: X.type = X$@6a9344f5
```

The script runner packages your lines of code this way:

```
object X {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    new AnyRef {
      val a = 10 + b
      lazy val b = 5
      println(a)
    }
}
```

If you give it an object with a `main` or that extends `App`, it won't wrap the code but just use it directly.

There are subtle differences between the three formulations. For example, the constructor of a top-level object is run as a static initializer; but an `App` is special-cased to run initializer code as `main`. (They're getting rid of `App` because it's confusing.)

Comment: Could you please provide the link for the `FAQ tutorial` you mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer.